# Replace a string and duplicate all rows containing it

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a data.table in R, where I would like to duplicate rows m times and replace a 'string' to 'string'_(m times).

Example table:

Input Table:
[image]
If number of repetitions is m ( say, m=2) then I would need the output table to look like this:
[image]
So for every row with OrderId, the output table should have m rows, where the OrderId is changed to OrderId_(1 to m) , like OrderId_1, OrderId_2 etc. The change should also happen to the ProdId field where there is OrdId prefix.

And the quantity needs to be incremented by 1 for every new row

Please guide me how to approach this in R. Any pointers would be of great help. Thank you.

Attempted approach:

```
m <- 20 # <-- number of rows desired

library(data.table)
Extra_COL <- Base_COL[rep(1:nrow(Base_COL), each=m),]
setDT(Extra_COL)

#Change OrderId
Extra_COL[, OrdId := paste0(OrdId,'_', seq_len(m)), by="OrdLineId"]

#Change Quantity
Extra_COL[, Quantity := Quantity + seq_len(m), by="OrdLineId"]

#New OrderId, so new ProductId. First split the existing ProductId
Extra_COL[, c('SOId', 'Item','Material','LevelId','ConfigId') := tstrsplit(ProductId,"|",fixed=TRUE)]

#Then, build the new productId
Extra_COL[, ProductId := paste(OrdId, Item, , Material, LevelId, ConfigId, sep='|')]
```

Comment: Hi Tino,   I have attempted many trials, just didnt mark it here in the question because I thought they were primitive. Please see updated question.  Please remove your downvote if you think I dont deserve it :(

Comment: I see. But your additional information makes it easier to help. Because for example one could build ProdId much easier if other information is available instead of changing string and so on... I'll post a solution using base R below.

Comment: have you been able to solve your using my approach below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this (`df` is your data frame):

```
m <- 20

Reduce(f = rbind,
       x = lapply(X = seq_len(m), 
                  FUN = function(i) {
                    # Modify ID:
                    df_mod <- transform(df, OrdId = paste(OrdId, i, sep = "_"))
                    # Modify ProdID with new ID:
                    df_mod <- transform(df_mod, ProdId = paste(OrdId, Item, Material, LevelId, ConfigId, sep = "|"))
                    return(df_mod)
                  }))
```